# SQL: Index nvarchar(2048) - Full text vs hash

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have two tables: `table1` holds a column `nvarchar(2048)` (unique values) and `table2` holds a reference to `table1` id.

Since I can't index `nvarchar(2048)` my question is, should I add a full-text index to `table1` or should I add another column to `table1` that holds a hash so that I can put an index on the hash column and then do checks against the hash column?

Data is inserted into `table2` after a check to `table1` is done to see if a value exists (if not, it is inserted into `table1`, then gets the id back for storing in `table2`).

That hash would not be computed in SQL.

What would be a better approach as far as scalability, data storage and performance?

Comment: See http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/05/indexing-wide-keys-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in such a case (the only important thing is to ensure uniqueness, no search/sorting needed) you can create a CLR UDF to generate hash, a computed persistent column that holds hash calculated by this function, and an unique constraint on that column.

Comment: computed column wont work. I need the value before SQL so it would be generated in the client code.

Comment: Why a unique constraint? This could cause problems with hash collisions?

Comment: @Martin : Indeed, it doesn't have to be unique. Just an index should work.

Comment: what would you recommend for the hash generation? I dont mind if it isn't unique. I'd rather have it small. It has to be fast. We're talking 10k records per second.